# How do I open WebStorm with WSL/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

I know with Visual Studio Code I can just use `code .` to open the directory inside of VSC. Is there an equivalent with WebStorm?

If I enter `wstorm` or `webstorm` I get a command not found error. I have tried using JetBrains Toolbox but that just generates `.cmd` files.

Comment: do you have webstorm installed in WSL? In such case, you can use "Tool | Create command line launcher" to generate a launcher

Comment: I have it installed in windows. I also have my VSC installed in windows but `code .` works fine in wsl anyways.

Comment: there is no commandline launcher for windows; you need adding the `<IDE install dir>/bin` forder to the system `%PATH%` to be able to launch the IDE from anywhere by entering `webstorm64.exe` (or `webstorm.bat`). See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.1/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#2e9e6f52

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this function

```
webstorm()
{
     /mnt/c/Program\ Files/JetBrains/WebStorm\ 2022.1.2/bin/webstorm64.exe "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 &!
}
```

to my zshrc file. I think it would work in the bashrc file too if you aren't using zsh.

With this there you can then type `webstorm .` to open the current directory in webstorm.